# Can't use mouse related function via LDTP(Python)

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I am trying to integrate LDTP and selenium in python environment for automation upload an image to "http://imgure.com/"

My environment as below:

- OS: Ubuntu 15.10
- Python: v3.5/v2.7
- IDE: Pycram 2016.1
- LDTP: v3.5

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import ldtp


  def main():
       browser = webdriver.Firefox()
       browser.implicitly_wait(5000)
       browser.get("http://imgur.com/")
       browser.maximize_window()
       browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li.upload-button-container").click()
       browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div#upload-global-file-wrapper").click()

       ldtp.maximizewindow("File Upload")
       #Call LDTP's mouserightclick function
       ldtp.mouseleftclick('File Upload', 'btnOpen')

       browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button#upload-global-start-button.button-big.green").click()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
  ```

My Pycram screenshot:

### [Pycram screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RaYi.png)

Pycram can't find mouseleftclick function when i try to use mouseleftclick.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I had similar problem but not while using ldap.
I solved it by adding "from ldtp import mouseleftclick" line at the top.

Comment: Thanks Anand. I will try your suggestion in environment.